# keras CNN with low and constant accuracies

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am dealing with the Street View House Number recognition problem. I am trying to train a CNN with Keras.

Here is how I prepared the input

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
train_folders = 'sv_train/train'
test_folders = 'test'
extra_folders = 'extra'
SV_IMG_SIZE = 28
SV_CHANNELS = 1
train_imsize = np.ndarray([len(train_data),2])
k = 500
sv_images = []
max_images = 20000#len(train_data)
max_digits = 5
sv_labels = np.ones([max_images, max_digits], dtype=int) * 10 # init to 10 cause it would be no digit
nboxes = [[] for i in range(max_images)]
print ("%d to load" % len(train_data))
def getBBox(i,perc):
    '''
    Given i, the desired i.png, returns
    x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max,
    the four numbers which define the small rectangular bounding
    box that contains all individual character bounding boxes
    '''
    boxes = train_data[i]['boxes'] 
    x_min=9990
    y_min=9990
    x_max=0
    y_max=0
    for bid,b in enumerate(boxes):
        x_min = b['left'] if b['left'] <= x_min else x_min
        y_min = b['top'] if b['top'] <= y_min else y_min
        x_max = b['left']+b['width'] if  b['left']+b['width'] >= x_max else x_max
        y_max = b['top']+b['height'] if b['top']+b['height'] >= y_max else y_max

    dy = y_max-y_min
    dx = x_max-x_min
    dpy = dy*perc
    dpx = dx*perc
    nboxes[i]=[dpx,dpy,dx,dy]
    return x_min-dpx, y_min-dpy, x_max+dpx, y_max+dpy

for i in range(max_images):
    print (" \r%d" % i ,end="")
    filename = train_data[i]['filename']
    fullname = os.path.join(train_folders, filename)
    boxes = train_data[i]['boxes']
    label = [10,10,10,10,10]
    lb = len(boxes)
    if lb <= max_digits:
        im = Image.open(fullname)
        x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = getBBox(i,0.3)
        im = im.crop([x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max])
        owidth, oheight = im.size
        wr = SV_IMG_SIZE/float(owidth)
        hr = SV_IMG_SIZE/float(oheight)
        for bid,box in  enumerate(boxes):
            sv_labels[i][max_digits-lb+bid] = int(box['label'])

        box = nboxes[i]
        box[0]*=wr
        box[1]*=wr
        box[2]*=hr
        box[3]*=hr
        im = im.resize((SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img = img - np.mean(img)
        im = im.filter(ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE)
        img = img - np.mean(img)

        array = np.asarray(im)
        array =  array.reshape((SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE,3)).astype(np.float32)
        na = np.zeros([SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE],dtype=int)
        for x in range (array.shape[0]):
            for y in range (array.shape[1]):
                na[x][y]=np.average(array[x][y][:])
        na = na.reshape(SV_IMG_SIZE,SV_IMG_SIZE,1)
        #print(array.shape)
        sv_images.append(na.astype(np.float32))

sv_train, sv_validation, svt_labels, svv_labels = train_test_split(sv_images, sv_labels, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

And here is how I created and trained the model

```
model = Sequential()
x = Input((28, 28,1))

y = Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, border_mode="same")(x)
#y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)) (y)
#y = Dropout(0.25)(y)

y = Convolution2D(32, 4, 4, border_mode="same")(y)
y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (3, 3)) (y)
#y = Dropout(0.25)(y)

y = Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode="same", activation="relu")(y)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
#y = Dropout(0.25)(y)

y = Convolution2D(128, 5, 5, border_mode="same", activation="relu")(y)
y = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(y)
#y = Dropout(0.25)(y)


y = Flatten()(y)
y = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(y)

digit1 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit2 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit3 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit4 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
digit5 = Dense(11, activation="softmax")(y)
model = Model(input=x, output=[digit1, digit2, digit3,digit4,digit5])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.layers[0].output_shape)
print(model.layers[2].output_shape)
print(model.layers[4].output_shape)
print(model.layers[6].output_shape)
print(model.layers[8].output_shape)

sv_train_labels = [svt_labels[:,0],svt_labels[:,1],svt_labels[:,2],svt_labels[:,3],svt_labels[:,4]]
sv_validation_labels = [svv_labels[:,0],svv_labels[:,1],svv_labels[:,2],svv_labels[:,3],svv_labels[:,4]]

model.fit(sv_train, sv_train_labels, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=64,validation_data=(sv_validation, sv_validation_labels))
```

The problem is I get very low accuracies that remain with the same value at each epoch

Train on 13400 samples, validate on 6600 samples
Epoch 1/10
13400/13400 [==============================] - 78s - loss: 34.7407 - dense_740_loss: 0.1161 - dense_741_loss: 0.6879 - dense_742_loss: 4.7988 - dense_743_loss: 14.7893 - dense_744_loss: 14.3486 - dense_740_acc: 0.9902 - dense_741_acc: 0.9542 - dense_742_acc: 0.7001 - dense_743_acc: 0.0810 - dense_744_acc: 0.1055 - val_loss: 34.7760 - val_dense_740_loss: 0.0049 - val_dense_741_loss: 0.7131 - val_dense_742_loss: 4.8721 - val_dense_743_loss: 14.8091 - val_dense_744_loss: 14.3769 - val_dense_740_acc: 0.9997 - val_dense_741_acc: 0.9558 - val_dense_742_acc: 0.6977 - val_dense_743_acc: 0.0812 - val_dense_744_acc: 0.1080
Epoch 2/10
13400/13400 [==============================] - 70s - loss: 34.7032 - dense_740_loss: 0.0036 - dense_741_loss: 0.6760 - dense_742_loss: 4.7861 - dense_743_loss: 14.8118 - dense_744_loss: 14.4257 - dense_740_acc: 0.9998 - dense_741_acc: 0.9581 - dense_742_acc: 0.7031 - dense_743_acc: 0.0810 - dense_744_acc: 0.1050 - val_loss: 34.7760 - val_dense_740_loss: 0.0049 - val_dense_741_loss: 0.7131 - val_dense_742_loss: 4.8721 - val_dense_743_loss: 14.8091 - val_dense_744_loss: 14.3769 - val_dense_740_acc: 0.9997 - val_dense_741_acc: 0.9558 - val_dense_742_acc: 0.6977 - val_dense_743_acc: 0.0812 - val_dense_744_acc: 0.1080

Answer (score 0):

Set the learning rate of adam according to your model. Instead of using the default adam you can instantiate the optimizer (https://keras.io/optimizers/#adam) yourself using:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
adam = Adam(lr=0.1)
```

This seems promising, because your loss is actually decreasing, just only by a very low margin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what the problem is, your loss is decreasing. The accuracy can only start changing very late in the process, your optimization happens on the loss. 
It might be also that your data set is biased, do you have the same number of samples in every classes ?